# If a new Android project has error on compiling time is my setup messed up?

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors

If so, How do I clean my setup to start with something fresh?

I'm trying to create a new project with minimum Android Version 9.0 and I'm getting the error

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction

I didn't changed a single line of the code generated by Android Studio, so why is not compiling the code that Android Studio itself generated.

Also I saw that the gradle now is Kotlin(kts files) Why?
Can I get back to the older way?

I don't use Android Studio too much and always something is changed and I feel like I'm fighting against Android IDE instead of concentrate my mind in the code that I'm trying to develop.

How do I clean my setup to start with something fresh?

Comment: Please update your question and include the full error message. Also you should add the command you execute which fails. Assuming the project worked once the one thing that may have changed over time is the used JDK, older versions if Android projects require JDK 8 or 11, recent 17.

Comment: @Robert I don't know what command you are talking about; is a clean project, I don't added not a single line from what IDE created. That's why I'm confused. If I can't trust and rely of one of the Android Studio templates something is really wrong. I just created New Project->Bottom Navigation Views Activity, put a name and that's it. Anyways, I uninstalled Giraffe version, installed JAVA SE SDK 11 and installed Iguana. and now seems to work ok. I hope it keeps running. and Google doesn't mess up everything with another "update" behind curtains.